# Переменные можно объявить только в конце

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Почему когда я пишу COM программу, то могу объявить переменные только в конце программы? То есть только вот так:

```
CSEG segment
assume cs:CSEG, ds:CSEG, es:CSEG, ss:CSEG
org 100h
Start:

    ...

    ;Variables
    A db 100
    B db 2
    C db -9
    D db 12
    nmr dw ?
    dnmr dw ?
    text1 db 'x = (a*(d^2-b)/(b^2*c^2+1)-40 = $'
CSEG ends
end Start
```

Если я объявляю переменные в начале кода, то программа компилируется без ошибок, но не работает вовсе. Использую компилятор TASM.

Comment: вы можете поставить первой командой jmp на метку, которая стоит после переменных. и тогда переменные будут почти в начале. просто в com программе данные в одном сегменте с кодом и лежат там куда вы их написали и когда они в самом начале они пытаются выполнится как код

Comment: В файлах данного типа,обычно не имеющими даже заголовка файла,содержатся только машинный код и данные программы.
Сначала код, потом данные.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka, `Сначала код, потом данные.` не верно. Данные в com файле могут быть где угодно, лишь бы в процессе выполнения программы процессор не начал их выполнять. Для этого достаточно через них "перепрыгнуть" с помощью `jmp`.

Comment: можно просто перепрыгнуть например `jmp $+10` (9 переменных)

Comment: иначе он вызовет ошибку что нет такого макроса / команды

Comment: @Duoxx, `jmp $+10` - тут еще нужно учитывать длину самой команды (2 байта в данном случае), и то что переменные могут быть не 1 байт размером. Поэтому лучше не извращаться, а сделать просто переход по метке.

Comment: @Duoxx, и про макросы точно не напишет, потому что в машинном коде нет никаких макросов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Для com файла выполнение всегда идет с начала файла, независимо от того, где вы поставите метку `start`. Для exe файла - если вы поставили в конце кода `end start`, то выполнение начнется с метки `start`. В com файле нет заголовка, это голый машинный код, там просто негде указать, откуда начать исполнение.
2. Для процессора нет разницы между данными и кодом (см. [Архитектура фон Неймана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0)), поэтому для процессора все равно, чем изначально были байты, встретившиеся ему на пути (переменными или командами), он все равно будет их считать командами. Соответственно, переменные, которые встретятся ему на пути в процессе выполнения будут для него просто каким-то странным кодом, и возможно выполнение прервется с ошибкой (а может и нет, но все равно происходить будет не то что вы хотели).

Чтобы избежать выполнения данных в вашем случае нужно в самом начале поставить `jmp` через данные, что-то вроде этого:

```
CSEG segment
assume cs:CSEG, ds:CSEG, es:CSEG, ss:CSEG
org 100h
    jmp start
    ; Variables
    A db 100
    B db 2
    C db -9
    D db 12
    nmr dw ?
    dnmr dw ?
    text1 db 'x = (a*(d^2-b)/(b^2*c^2+1)-40 = $'
    ...
start:
    ; Code

CSEG ends
end start ; опять же, end start ни на что не повлияет, выполнение будет с начала файла, а не с метки
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что в ассемблере нет переменных как таковых. Есть именованные последовательности байтов. Причем имена нужны только компилятору, который в места их использования подставит адреса начала последовательностей. Соответственно для программы все равно

```
db 0x90
```

или

```
nop
```

все это будет одним и тем же байтом.

Таким образом, если Вы как-то резервируете какие-то значения, то Вам нужно обеспечить, чтобы эти значения не начали выполняться. Сделать это можно разными способами

1. Поместить в другой сегмент
2. Перепрыгнуть через эти значения
3. Выйти до этих значений

COM-программа подразумевает наличие одного сегмента, значит первый способ не доступен

Для перепрыгивания нужна дополнительная команда `jmp`. Можно и поставить, но зачем, если можно просто разместить переменные после выхода из программы и сэкономить один джамп?